# How to remove contents from list

Tags: c#, list

I'm very new to coding. Is there any other way through which I can write this code to remove contents from list in c#?

```cs
public void RemoveItem(string itemDescription)
{
    MenuItem found = new MenuItem(false, 0, "", ""); // must be a better way - to fix

    foreach (MenuItem item in MenuItems)
    {
        if (item.Description == itemDescription)
        {
            found = item;
        }
    }

    MenuItems.Remove(found);
}
```

Comment: "must be a better way"
 Yes, assign `null` anf check if it's null where you remove it.

Comment: What type is `MenuItems`? If it is a `List<MenuItem>` you can do `MenuItems.RemoveAll(item => item.Description == itemDescription);`

Comment: There's probably a method on `MenuItems` that you can use, but failing that it's more streamlined here, IMO, to do `MenuItems.Remove(item); return;` within the `if` and dispense with the `found` variable.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay This would remove all menu items fulfilling the condition, but OP's code only removes the last menu item fulfilling the condition.

Comment: @SomeBody Yeah, I'm making the assumption that removing only the last item that matches isn't the intended behaviour.

Comment: @SomeBody: it removes the first instance of the item that was found last.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways how to improve this code. Some of them were already mentioned.

---

As commented by @tim-schmelter

```
// removes the last matching occurrence from the menu and avoids the "dummy" object
public void RemoveItem(string itemDescription)
{
    MenuItem found = null; // this is better

    foreach (MenuItem item in MenuItems)
    {
        if (item.Description == itemDescription)
        {
            found = item;
        }
    }

    if (found != null)
        MenuItems.Remove(found);
}
```

---

As originally answered by @SomeBody

```
// removes the first matching occurrence from the menu
public void RemoveItem(string itemDescription)
{
    foreach (MenuItem item in MenuItems)
    {
        if (item.Description == itemDescription)
        {
            MenuItems.Remove(found);
            break; // or return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// same but replacing the loop with a LINQ approach
public void RemoveItem(string itemDescription)
{
    MenuItem found = MenuItems.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Description == itemDescription);

    if (found != null)
        MenuItems.Remove(found);
}
```

---

```
// removing all occurences (assumes that MenuItems is from type `List<MenuItem>`
public void RemoveItem(string itemDescription)
{
    MenuItems.RemoveAll(item => item.Description == itemDescription);
}
```

---

```
// assuming List<MenuItem>, removing the first occurrence only
public void RemoveItem(string itemDescription)
{
    int index = MenuItems.Find(item => item.Description == itemDescription);

    if (index >= 0)
        MenuItems.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `MenuItems` is a `List<MenuItem>`.

In which case, as Johnathan says in the comments `MenuItems.RemoveAll(item => item.Description == itemDescription);` will remove all elements in the list that match your criteria and is probably the most efficient option:

```
public void RemoveItem(string itemDescription)
{
    MenuItems.RemoveAll(item => item.Description == itemDescription);
}
```

Ideally, though, I'd use an ID field to make sure you're definitely removing the right element.

Answer (score 0):

@geraldmayr answer is great.

Only thing I would change is the approach of the original answer in LINQ to make it a clean one liner.

```
    public static void RemoveItem(string itemDescription)
    {
        menuItems.Remove(menuItems.First(menuItem => menuItem.ItemDescription == itemDescription));
    }
```

Comment: You are right. `List<T>.Remove()` accepts null. But for the costs of an additional lookup of a definitely not existing `null` in the list.

Comment: `List<T>.Find()` would throw an ArgumentNullException if no element was found that satisfies the condition so there is no possibility of getting into an additional lookup. But that was my intention since I imagine the correct behavior to be an Exception throw if you're trying to delete an item that doesn't exist.

Comment: I meant, if an item matching the item description is not found, `Find` will return `null`, and so `Remove` will be called with `null` resulting in an addition traversal within `Remove`

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks for the correction. I mixed up `List<T>.Find()` and `List<T>.First()` which does throw an exception if no element was found satisfying the condition. I'm going to edit the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective there is another solution which especially makes sense if a list grows very huge or is traversed very often (which is hopefully not the case for a menu list).

Most of the so far given answers require two lookups (one for finding the item, one for removing the item), or have some overhead by calling a predicate function.

The following is probably the fastest method and works with every collection implementing `IList<T>`:

```
// remove last matching item
public void RemoveItem(string itemDescription)
{
    for (int i = MenuItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) // reverse for-loop, to avoid Count property call on each iteration
    {
        if (MenuItems[i].Description == itemDescription)
        {
            MenuItems.RemoveAt(i);
            return;
        }
    }
```